# Unable to insert char string into char array

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop, multidimensional-array

```
  int row = 5;
  int column = 10;
  char **array;
  int rowcount = 0;
  array = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);
  char *x_ptr = array;
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    array[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * column);
    x_ptr[i] = (int *) malloc(column * sizeof(int));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {

    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        rowcount += 1;
        char snum[5] = {'\0'};
        sprintf(snum, "%d", rowcount); //converts int to char
        for (int t = 0; t < strlen(snum); t++)
          *(x_ptr + (i * column + j) + t) = snum[t];
      } else {
        *(x_ptr + (i * column + j)) = 0;
      }
    }
```

Just trying to add some integer values to the array on column 0. However when trying to add numbers such as 10, sprintf command split the value into snum[0]=49'1' and snum[1]=48'0'. But the array only takes in snum[0] and snum[1] is completely ignored.

Please correct me if my understanding of the pointer position is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read this: [ask] and post a [MCVE].

Comment: Step 1 for working with C code: Set your compiler at highest warning level and treat all warnings as errors. Your code generates multiple warnings, e.g. **assignment from incompatible pointer type** and **assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast**. You need to fix those warnings before you try to run the program.

Comment: You should not be casting to eliminate warning (except to `(void*)` when printing pointer values with `"%p"`). If you are otherwise casting to avoid warnings -- you are likely doing something wrong. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: 1) Review `char *x_ptr = array;`  2) Why declare to type `char` with `char **array;` and then allocate to `int` with `array[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*column);`?  Recommend `array[i] = malloc(sizeof *(array[i]) * column);` to avoid such type mis-matches.

Comment: "But the array only takes in .." --> And how is this known?  Is is likely that the code used to determine this is not resilient to printing `x_ptr[i][i]` - `x_ptr[i][i]` is not a _string_ without a _null character_.

Comment: `x_ptr[i] = (int *) malloc(column * sizeof(int));` Does your compiler complain a bit on that line? What is the type of `x_ptr[i]` and can it hold an `int*`?

Comment: @gerhardh It didnt complain about that. But i removed it anyway. But my main problem of not being able to fit int 10 into the array is still the main issue.

Comment: You did not answer chux' question how you know this.

Comment: @chux I need to store char variable in  **array. if that is that case, it is probably because I'm placing both char value separately each with a null character into the same pointer. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've tried really hard, but there are *so* many things wrong with this code that it's basically irretrievable. Please look carefully at the comments above, post some code which is compilable, tell us what you expect it to do, what it *does* do and what the difference is between those two things.

At the core of this enigma is perhaps that you're using two different techniques to access a two-dimensional array. Let's say you want to have an array of integers with `n` rows and `m` columns. You might do this by declaring:

```
int **array1 = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
for (int a=0; a<n; a++)
  array1[a] = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
```

This way you access the integer in row `i` and column `j` as `array1[i][j]`.

Alternatively, you can do this by declaring:

```
int *array2 = malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));
```

and accessing the integer in row `i` and column `j` as `array2[i * m + j]`.

Here's some code which should compile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int row = 5;
int column = 10;
//  char **array;  // declaration moved into main()
int rowcount = 0;

int main(void) {  // added main() function
  int **array = malloc(sizeof(int *) * row); // include type (int **); remove cast: (int **); moved into main()
  int **x_ptr = array;  // changed type to int **; moved into main()

  // Allocate memory for array, so we can assign integers to
  //   array[i][j] where:
  //     i <= 0 < column
  //     j <= 0 < column
  //  Note that:
  //    array[i]
  //  is identical to:
  //    *(array + i)
  //  and:
  //    array[i][j]
  //  is identical to:
  //    *(*(array + i) + j)
  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    // array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * column);  // removed cast, you're not using array[] anyway
    x_ptr[i] = malloc(column * sizeof(int));  // removed cast
  } 

  for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
  {

    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      if (j == 0) {
        rowcount += 1;

        // Create a character buffer.
        char snum[5] = {'\0'};

        // Write the text version of integer "rowcount" into the char
        //   buffer "snum"
        sprintf(snum, "%d", rowcount); //converts int to char

        // Copy the char value of each character into the
        //   two-dimensional integer array. We want to copy
        //   snum[t] into array[i][t]
        for (size_t t = 0; t < strlen(snum); t++)
          // *(x_ptr + (i * column + j) + t) = snum[t];
          array[i][t] = snum[t];
      } else {
        // *(x_ptr + (i * column + j)) = 0;
        array[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<column; j++)
      printf("Row %d, column %d has value %d\n", i, j, array[i][j]);

  return 0;
}
```

I have the file saved as `so.c` and I'm using the following command to compile it:

```
gcc -o so -W -Wall -pedantic so.c
```

This switches on warnings for many of the things you don't want to be doing in your original code. It probably doesn't solve the exact problem you have, but it should give you something to work from.